# Android RecognizerIntent: slow to return results

Tags: android, performance, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

Ever since the current version of Google Now came out (as of 2014-03-18), if I use the RecognizerIntent to start voice recognition it sits there for several seconds before finally giving me the results.

Any one else with the same issue?
Thanks in advance.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Intent intentRecognize = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intentRecognize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
                    intentRecognize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say stuff");
                    intentRecognize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intentRecognize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10);

                startActivityForResult(intentRecognize, requestCode);
```

Comment: I see this too, hope it will be fixed soon. Consider other toolkits for now.

Comment: Do you have a good alternative?